# Visiting Bosnia-Herzegovina during Ramadan

Tags: bosnia, ramadan

I am considering a trip that will include Bosnia-Herzegovina, and wonder if it is difficult to eat in a restaurant there during the day during Ramadan (as is the case in many majority-Muslim countries).

If I were traveling under other circumstances, I wouldn't let this be a factor: I can certainly abstain from food or drink during the daytime, and would enjoy experiencing this aspect of another culture. But the person I'm traveling with is diabetic, and needs to manage his blood sugar carefully -- so skipping or delaying meals is not an option for him.

I suspect that there is enough of a non-Muslim presence throughout Bosnia-Herzegovina that our travel would not be impacted substantially by Ramadan, but I'd appreciate guidance from those more familiar with the environment there.

Comment: Thanks @pnuts, that information about Sarajevo during Ramadan was helpful. I'd still be interested in what it's like in more Muslim areas of the country during Ramadan.

Comment: There's a very interesting (to me, at least) paper at the NIH on ["Recommendations for management of Diabetes during Ramadan."](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2909082/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm from Bosnia. I myself never partake in Ramadan and I've never had any serious troubles. As you said yourself, Bosnia has a large non-Muslim presence throughout the whole country. Many Muslims don't fast during Ramadan as well. Some just choose not to, but some can't because of illness, pregnancy, old age or physical work/exercise etc. On top of that, most places that are touristy stay open to make money. Yes, there will be restaurants that are closed during the fasting but my experience has been that it is at most an small inconvenience. Definitely not a reason to not visit.

Perhaps if you tell me where you're visiting exactly that I could tell you more.

Answer (score 3):

My thoughts on this topic available on personal blog

http://www.glowhunters.com/visiting-sarajevo-during-ramadan-and-bayram/

Would be happy if you visit and leave your comment. Blog is in preparation of much more touristic reviews of Balkans and whole Western Europe. But still, Sarajevo has a special role as this is my home town...So be welcomed to sneak and peek! :)

http://www.glowhunters.com/visiting-sarajevo-during-ramadan-and-bayram/

Comment: Welcome to the site. We usually discourage link only answers, if you could perhaps expand a little more on that here, it would be more helpful

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Travel-SE! You seem to be new to the Stack Exchange network, and since you have a blog that you linked to, I'd like to point out [the page in the Help Center about self-promotion](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/promotion). There's nothing wrong with redirecting users to your product/site, provided it answers the question (which in this case does -- an interesting write!). It's recommended to write a self-contained answer and provide links as support and source of additional information. Thanks, and we're looking forward to more of your contributions in the future!

Comment: Glowhunters link is dead as of 2022-04-13.